# How to add more images into sdcard same time in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi am doing one application,here i need to select more images from gallery folder or camera.and then i need to save those selected images into  sdcard some other folder..using below code i can able to select images from gallery then am storing selected images in one string arraylist,but how to store those selected images into sdcard...

```
  public class MultiPhotoSelectActivity extends BaseActivity {
private Button dialogButton1,dialogButton2,dialogButton3,cancel;
Dialog dialog;
String extStorageDirectory;

Bitmap bm;
private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
final Context context = this;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);

    //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy + " DESC");

    this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

        System.out.println("=====> Array path => "+imageUrls.get(i));
    }


    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageUrls);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startImageGalleryActivity(position);
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    imageLoader.stop();
    super.onStop();
}


public void btnChoosePhotosClick(View v){

ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
        }

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> mList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context mContext;
    SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mList = imageList;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<mList.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(mList.get(i));
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
        }

        CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+imageUrls.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MultiPhotoSelectActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }
        });

        mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

        return convertView;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: yes...i got it.. down posted person he mailed me code

Comment: you are talking about multiple image selection and save id sdcard.. right..??

Comment: yes...now able to select multiple images in sdcard..and saving same where

Comment: yeah i know because i sent that code to you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31794/discussion-between-segi-and-user2401554)

Comment: come in discussion chat...

Comment: sory i cant able to chat with you..am enter data and sending to you..but its not posting in chat

Comment: its okey..talk u ltr on gmail..

Comment: yeah, i m trying... come on gmail now..

Answer (score 0):

```
private void saveDataInSdCard(String urimg) {
 URL url = new URL(urimg);

    OutputStream fOut = null;
    Uri outputFileUri;
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "urFlodername" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root,i+"myPicName.jpg");
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    try {
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }       

}
```

then call this method on your for loop of image list..

```
For(int i = 0; i < imagesUrls.size(); i++){
        saveDataInSdCard(imagesUrls.get(i)); }
```

Comment: thankyou...i gave like below ArrayList<String> selectedItems1 = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
      
      for(int i=0;i<selectedItems1.size();i++)
      {
       saveDataInSdCard();
      }

Comment: saveDataInSdCard(); in this line inside for loop,its asking create method..do i need to pass any arguments here

Comment: are you storing url of that image into arraylist.??

Comment: i dnt hav any uri of image, i am having all images inside selecteditms1 arraylist..can you see my above code once

Comment: hi i edited my  code can u see inside btnChoosePhotosClick method..now inside selecteditems1 arraylist all images what ever i selected those images is there

Comment: what are you storing in arraylist..??

Comment: i too dnt knw exactly..but that line obsrve once using imageAdapter they are storing

Comment: imageUrls is here string array list..but we need to pass url as method argument.

Comment: thnks..i passed,but its asking create method saveDataInSdCard(String)

Comment: @Aditya have you used my above answer.?